# Convert QString with UTF-8 (hex) into QString

Tags: c++, qt

Basically, I have a string like `"Sam\xe2\x80\x99s phone"` and I want to convert that to be `"Sam’s phone"`.

What is the easiest way to do that in Qt or C++?

I could loop through every character and look for `\x`, and convert all characters to hex values (except the two digits after every `\x`), and then convert it to string but is there a better way?

EDIT:

```
void someFunction(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
    QProcess *someQProcess = reinterpret_cast<QProcess*>(sender());
    QString output = someQProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    QStringList data = output.split("\n");
    parseScan(data);
}

void parseScan(QStringList data){
    QStringList nameList;
    for(int i = 2; i < data.size(); i++ ){
        QStringList dataLine  = data[i].split("\t");
        if(dataLine.size() == 5){
            QString name = dataLine[4];  // name is "Sam\xe2\x80\x99s phone"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on _QString with UTF-8_? Do you have this data as a string literal? Please show your relevant code also.

Comment: @Azeem I have added the code

Comment: What do you get when you print `name`? Isn't it what you expect?

Comment: Actually I get "Sam\\xe2\\x80\\x99s phone", but I want "Sam’s phone"

Comment: Right. Try: `QString name = QString::fromUtf8( dataLine[4].toUtf8() );`

Comment: still the same..

Comment: Can you add the data you're passing to `parseScan()`?

Comment: What do you get when you print `output`?

Comment: I get "Sam\\xe2\\x80\\x99s phone", but in the terminal, when i run the same command I run in the QProcess, it appears as "Sam\xe2\x80\x99s phone",

Comment: What your process does ? It read a file with those characters ?

Comment: @thibsc it read "Sam\xe2\x80\x99s phone" from the command line

Comment: @Gebre So your process does for example just `echo "Sam\xe2\x80\x99s phone"` ?

Comment: it does 'wpa_cli scan_results'
which scans for wifi, and it reads the output

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the way you read the standard output. Indeed, your standard output has a poor chance to be utf-8.
I tried to reproduce the same behavior with `echo`:

```cpp
QProcess *p = new QProcess();
p->start("echo \"Sam\xe2\x80\x99s phone\"", QProcess::ReadOnly);
p->waitForFinished();

/* Read without conversion: */
qDebug() << p->readAllStandardOutput();
// "Sam\xE2\x80\x99s phone\n"

/* Read with conversion: */
qDebug() << QString::fromLocal8Bit(p->readAllStandardOutput());
// "Sam’s phone\n"
```